# Regular expression to extract not more than ten words between double quotes

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group

Could anyone please guide me to write a regex to find maximum of ten words in a quoted string?

```
string = "\"Michael Jackson is a great singer\". There were many rumours about his relationship with his girlfriend.  \"He won many national awards and one of the most famous pop singer in the late 80s and 90s\""
re.findall(r'"(.*)"', string)
```

The above regex extracts both the quoted string but I want to extract only the quoted string which has less than 10 words

Comment: Your sample string is invalid. Add single quotes around them.

Comment: maximum of ten words meaning it can be anything below 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.findall(r'"[^\s"]+(?:\s+[^\s"]+){,9}"', string)
```

Explanation:

You want to find up to 10 space separated words between double quotes. The first and the last `"` limit this expression to quoted phrases only.

(Not really, as it suggests using `".+"` would work. But then you get the entire string from the *first* quote up to the *last* one, because GREP is Greedy. You can use `".+?"` to find the *shortest* matches only, but then you cannot 'count' the words inside.)

After the first quote, you want to match the first 'entire word', which will necessarily consist of a sequence of non-space characters: `\S+`. However, that *might* eat up the closing double quote if you only have a single word and continue after that, so it is necessary to exclude that as well:

```
[^\s"]+
```

-- a sequence of one or more *not*(space character or double quote). This will match the first word. Then, zero or up to 9 sequences of "space -- word-like sequence" may follow:

```
\s+[^\s"]+
```

matches a single occurrence of these, and

```
(\s+[^\s"]+){,9}
```

matches 0 up to 9 occurrences.

You may not have noticed it but your own attempt *discarded* the double quotes at the start and end. That is because you used parentheses in your regex, and `findall` returns this as a *group*. To prevent this, I used `?:` at the start of the group. (And without this, you will get just `singer`, the contents of the last group that matched!)

If you don't want the quotes, strip them off later or add a new explicit group around the entire regex:

```
>>> re.findall(r'"([^\s"]+(?:\s+[^\s"]*){,9})"', string)
['Michael Jackson is a great singer']
```

Comment: Awesome!! Exact answer which I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

try the following regex:

```
\"(\b\w+\b\s?){,10}\"
```

[demo regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/4jSjb9/1)

explanation:

- `\"` matches `"`
- `\"(\b\w+\b\s?)` matches a word followed by space with space being optional
- `{,10}` quantifier specifies less than or equal to `10` words
- `\"` matches the last `"`

if your sentences contain punctuation marks at the end, you can use to to match `[\.\?\!]` and make it optional

```
\"(\b\w+\b\s?){,10}[\.\?\!]?\"
```

Comment: This cannot work in case the sentence ends with a period or question mark or any other punctuation. since all those are considered non word. what you are actually looking for is `(?<=\")(?:\b[^\" ]+\s?){,10}(?=\s*\")`

Comment: the OP does not specify in his question that words will contain punctuation marks.

Comment: But a sentence can end with anything. eg `"You know it."` although this sentence is below ten words, your regex cannot capture it. Also look for example the second part of OP's string. it is exactly 10 words. If it had `"` involved, your regex cannot capture it

Answer (score 0):

By default, regular expressions are greedy, which means that they will try to match as much as possible. What you need to do is then say that you want the non-greedy matcher by using `.*?`. But this will match the whole string.

So what you need to create is a regular expression that matches a word, but not spaces, and then at most 9 others (starting with spaces).

All the information required to build this is in the documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: could you please give me one example for this regex? As I am new to regex, I have no idea about this

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be written as follow:

```
string = "Michael Jackson is a great singer". There were many rumours about his relationship with his girlfriend.  "He won many national awards and one of the most famous pop singer in the late 80s and 90s"
re.findall(r'"(\w* ){0,9}\w*"', string)
```

`"(\w* ){0,9}` --> to match 0 to 9 word(s) after a opened quote(")

`\w*"` --> to match the last word comming before an ended quote(")

Comment: did you test your regex?